# Why does it use the term "object" here when mentioning a prvalue?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, semantics, value-categories

As far as I know,in c++17 the concept/semantic of prvalue is **no longer temporary object**,so in many circumstances the copy elision is mandated.

However, today I came cross a description of [return expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return)

> If expression is a prvalue, **the object returned by the function** is initialized directly by that expression. This does not involve a copy or move constructor when the types match

Why does the term **object** occurs here?  In **value category** the return of function which is not a reference type belongs to **prvalue**,so I think maybe it is inappropriate to use the term **object**.

According to my understanding,the **prvalues** are no longer **objects** now,they are just values,am I right?

As a supplement,[here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html) also use the term "object".

Comment: An object and its value type are orthogonal.

A prvalue indicates the value type of object. There is still an object involved.

Comment: @RSahu If that's true,how to comprehend the "prvalue is not temporary object" ?

Comment: @RSahu What's more,prvalue indicates the value_type of **expression**,not **object**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with what you say. There is a discussion page on cppreference where you can raise your concerns. A better way to phrase it might be

> If *expression* is a prvalue, the result object of the *expression* is initialized directly by that expression.

As you say, objects are no longer returned or passed around by prvalues.

Comment: What do you mean by "result object",is it a **prvalue**?

Comment: @bigxiao See http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#basic.lval-5.sentence-3 . A result object of a prvalue may have more than a single prvalue that initialize it. So one cannot point at a prvalue and say that it "creates" an object. The creation is done by whoever supplies the result object.

Answer (score 3):

The quoted text is pointing out that there is an object whose value is set to the return value of the function: with C++17's guaranteed elision when returning *by value*, that object will be something like a variable being created by the caller, an element in a vector the caller is emplacing or push_backing too, or an object being constructed in some dynamically allocated memory the caller's orchestrated.  You're confusing this with a temporary, which as you say might not be involved.

Working through it systematically, you quote cppreference saying of...

```
return expression;
```

...that...

> If expression is a prvalue, the object returned by the function is initialized directly by that expression. This does not involve a copy or move constructor when the types match

The C++17 Standard says in [basic.lval]:

> The *result* of a `prvalue` is the value that the expression stores into its context. [ ... ] The *result object* of a `prvalue` is the object initialized by the `prvalue`; a `prvalue` that is used to compute the value of an operand of an operator or that has type *cv* `void` has no result object. [ *Note*: Except when the `prvalue` is the operand of a *decltype-specifier*, a `prvalue` of class or array type always has a result object. For a discarded `prvalue`, a temporary object is materialized; ...

So, in the cppreference text, what the standard terms the "*result object*" is being referred to as *"the object returned by the function"*.  The language is a little bit imprecise in saying the result object is "returned" rather than "initialised", but overall it's not misleading and - for having avoided yet another bit of terminology - may well be easier for most cppreference readers to understand.  I'm not actively involved with the site, but as a regular user my impression is that cppreference is trying to accurately explain the essence of the standard but simplifying language a smidge when possible.

---

While the underlying mechanisms are left unspecified by the Standard - and the practicalities of optimisation / ABIs dictate different implementation - to get a sense of what the Standard requires happen functionally it *might* help to imagine the compiler implementing code like...

```
My_Object function() { return { a, b, c }; }
...
... {
    My_Object my_object = function();  // caller
}
```

...by secretly passing a memory-for-returned-object address to the function (much like the `this` pointer to member functions)...

```
void function(My_Object* p_returned_object) {
    new (p_returned_object) My_Object{ a, b, c };
}
```

So, there is an object involved and constructed by the called function, but its whereabouts is elided - i.e. a caller-specified memory address.  If the function call result is unused by the caller, a temporary is at least notionally constructed then destructed.

Comment: But the **object** in the quoted paragraph is not created by caller,it's the return of function(or created by function call)  according to the context.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "created": it's really a cooperative effort: which memory is used for the object is orchestrated by the caller, but the object is constructed by the called function as it returns.

Comment: [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html) Also use the term "object",which maybe not ambiguous.

Comment: There's a lot in the link you provide above - I'm not sure which bits of it confuse you.  I've added some more to my answer that I hope will help you understand what's happening when a function returns by value.

Comment: @TonyDelroy the called function does not assume that it constructs an object. It simply specifies an initialization, which is checked for validity. But whether an object is actually initialized depends on the caller and the presence of a "result object" for the prvalue.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: basic.lval 6.10.2 *"Except when the prvalue is the operand of a decltype-specifier, a prvalue of class or array type always has a result object. For a discarded prvalue, a temporary object is materialized;"* - doesn't this mean the called function could assume it will construct an object (in my mythical implementation) - it's just that the caller might pass "`&temp`"?  Seems consistent with the mental model I've suggested might help bigxiao understand the eliding behaviour.  Of course "as if" optimisation can kick in and remove processing without side effects....

Comment: @TonyDelroy I think you are missing the "Except".

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I'm not... the exception is for `decltype(function())` - not relevant to this question, and it's saying that's the only time there's no result object.  The "discarded prvalue" situation is the one you're alluding to above in saying the called function may not actually initialize an object, but the part of the standard I quote says it "materialize[s]" a temporary object.